# Workaround for image size limitation in iMacros

Tags: image, size, imacros

There is a 10000px image size limitation in iMacros for firefox i.e. When the length of a webpage is greater than 10000px, the {{SAVEAS TYPE=JPEG}} does not capture the entire page. Is there a workaround to it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest this way:

```
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=entirepage
TAG POS=1 TYPE=HTML ATTR=* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVE_ELEMENT_SCREENSHOT
```

and hope that the image height can be up to 65536 px.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Shugar. I am using Windows 7. Firefox version 44.0.2 and iMacros version Build 8970419. What is your configuration? Also note that the the command that I shared in my question generates complete image on Ubuntu but not on Windows OS. Can you please help me in understanding this?

Comment: I think that such issues should be addressed to the 'iMacros' developers (e.g. [here](http://forum.imacros.net/)).

Comment: I am accepting this answer as this does resolve the issue on a linux machine. I created an internal ticket on iMacro's developer forum last year and they said they are working on something else at the moment. Thanks a lot Shugar for you help on this.